# Source file list from a Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio, makefile

Is there any way of passing the list of source files, that Visual Studio would build, to a makefile. Ideally Visual Studio would set an environment variable with a list of the files to compile. But unfortunately I have not discovered such a variable. I know I could write a script to parse the project file but I would really like to find a method which does not rely on a script. I would like to be able to set up the Visual Studio project so that different source files are built depending on the build configuration, using the Exclude from Build option. I would then like the makefile to only build the files that were not excluded. I am attempting to use Visual Studio as the development environment for a project which runs on different hardware and OS combinations.

P.S. Using Visual Studio is non-optional, and not my personal choice.

Comment: What is the point of using a make file if you already have a VS project? Note that VS has support for makefile projects as well. This seems to be an XY problem.

Comment: Maybe you need a tool like CMake? It builds makefiles for different IDE and compilers including MSVS.

Comment: If cross-platform build support is what you're after, and one of the targeted build systems is Visual Studio, then you're probably better off working in the opposite direction.  Although I personally tend to prefer the Autotools, this particular problem is [CMake's](https://cmake.org/) bread & butter.  a CMake-based build system can generate both project files for VS and conventional Makefiles for everything else, plus it provides access to facilities for configuring the result appropriately for the target machine.

Comment: C tag - as defined in SO - is not relevant: deleted (by someone other than me who included c++ tag as well)

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to opine that VS is not your personal choice. It's an excellent IDE and anybody who gives you flack for this doesn't know what they're talking about. I may prefer `gcc` as a compiler or the way Eclipse or Xcode handles things as an IDE...but Visual Studio is a top shelf, AAA development toolchain, exceeding most others on the market.

Comment: Judging by the response and my own research, it does not look like there is a simple way to extract the file list from Visual Studio. While I could use CMake this is introducing yet another tool. Currently we just add files manually to a makefile and I was hoping to remove this step, but it is not a big enough issue to require a new tool. Yes, I am wanting to do cross platform development but my target is an embedded system which uses a compile that is based on GCC, hence we can't use VS NMAKE.

Answer (score 0):

Create a MakeFile project within the VS solution.

This should be found under `File -> New -> Project -> Visual C++ -> Other -> Makefile Project`

Using Visual Studio 2017, there is a MakeFile template that can be used.

Additional instructions on how to do so can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/creating-a-makefile-project?view=vs-2017)

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for some way to export the file list from the Visual Studio project so I could use it in my makefile.

Comment: If you right click the .vcxproj file in the solution directory and search for the .cpp extension, this will give you files. However, obviously this is manual and not automated.